SwiftUI LazyVGrid Inconsistent Item Widths Issue
I am new to SwiftUI and am learning it by making my application. I'm experiencing an issue with LazyVGrid in SwiftUI where the item widths are inconsistent. I'm trying to create a grid with a header and several items, but as you can see in the screenshot below, the items do not have uniform widths, leading to an uneven appearance.
I remove all leading&trailing modifiers, including items view to clarify behavior. When I add any modifiers to adjust items' widths, they are still different widths.
Does anybody know what kind of behavior is like this? How to maintain it?
struct IdeasView: View {
    
    let store: StoreOf<IdeasFeature>
    
    var gridItems: [GridItem] {
        if UIDevice.isIPad {
            [
                .init(.flexible(), spacing: 8),
                .init(.flexible(), spacing: 8)
            ]
        } else {
            [
                .init()
            ]
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        self.content
            .onLoad {
                self.store.send(.view(.onViewLoad))
            }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var content: some View {
        WithViewStore(self.store, observe: { $0 }) { viewStore in
            NavigationStackStore(self.store.scope(state: \.path,
                                                  action: \.path)) {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: self.gridItems,
                              spacing: 10) {
                        Section {
                            ForEachStore(
                                self.store.scope(state: \.initalItems,
                                                 action: \.idea)
                            ) { itemStore in
                                IdeaItemView(store: itemStore)
                            }
                        } header: {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Here will be header with searchbar")
                                    .background(Color.teal)
                                    .frame(height: 130)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .modifier(NavigationBarModifier())
                .loader(isLoading: viewStore.isLoading)
                .refreshable {
                    await viewStore.send(.view(.onPulledToRefresh), while: \.isLoading)
                }
            } destination: {
                switch $0 {
                case .details:
                    CaseLet(/IdeasFeature.Path.State.details,
                             action: IdeasFeature.Path.Action.details,
                             then: IdeaDetailsView.init(store:)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



I tried to make GridItem for iPhone with .fixed(Value). In this case, items have a consistent width. So it's my back plan to calculate width somehow with GeometryReader. But it doesn't look like a good approach.
Codes for other connected Views:
IdeaItemView
struct IdeaItemView: View {
    
    let store: StoreOf<IdeaItemFeature>
    
    var body: some View {
        CardView {
            content
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.store.send(.view(.onItemTap))
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var content: some View {
        WithViewStore(self.store, observe: { $0 }) { viewStore in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                Text(viewStore.idea.idea)
                Text(viewStore.idea.description)
                Text(viewStore.idea.createdDate.description)
            }
        }
    }
}


CardView
struct CardView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            content()
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16.0)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10.0)
    }
}


Update:
I experimented more with .fixed width for GridItem. The widths of items are still inconsistent. So, my possible trick with GeometryReader will not work either (I experimented with this as well to be sure).

Can you share the code for IdeaItemView?

@Timmy I have added code for item and its container view

Just add this line with maxWidth to the CardView component BEFORE background modifier.
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        content()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(16.0)
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10.0)
}

